# p:selectonemenu not being populated

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to populate a p:selectOneMenu like this:

(xhtml)

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="perfil" value="#{criarContaBean.idPerfil}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""/>
                <f:selectItems values="#{criarContaBean.perfis}"></f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
private void carregarPerfis() {
        ControladorPerfil c = new ControladorPerfil();
        List<Perfil> lista = c.consultarPerfis();
        perfis = new HashMap<Long, String>();
        for (Perfil perfil : lista) {
            perfis.put(perfil.getId(), perfil.getDescricao());
        }

    }

public HashMap<Long, String> getPerfis() {
    return perfis;
}
```

The method is called in the init method, but when i run my page, only the selectitem shows up. What am i missing?

EDIT: i've discovered the problem...it's `value="#{criarContaBean.perfis}"`...not `values`...

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You mean to say that the `getPerfis()` method call returned an empty map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BalusC said, you may have empty map. Otherwise, you are trying to use `f:selectItems` with `Map`, not `Collection`.

Try as below :

```
<f:selectItems value="#{criarContaBean.perfis.entrySet()}" var="data" 
itemValue="#{data.key}" itemLabel="#{data.value}" />
```

Comment: Since JSF 2.0, `<f:selectItems>` supports maps. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info OP doesn't seem to be using JSF 1.x given presence of PrimeFaces components.